# Is it possible to apply no lock at DB/Table level for all queries hitting on thd DB /TBL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamics-crm-2013

I am not sure even that this is valid question. But I will explain my situation and probable get an answer from experts like you.

We have on primes MS Dynamics installed. We are observing very slow performance.
We are looking at APP Log server. **we are noticing 4-5 warning messages per second** about "**Query Execution time exceeded 10.seconds threshold"**

Here is an example of the error and related query.
**Query execution time of 27.7 seconds exceeded the threshold of 10 seconds. Thread: 109; Database: Main_MSCRM;**

```
select 
top 5001 "systemuser0".QueueId as "queueid"
, "systemuser0".CreatedBy as "createdby"
, "systemuser0".Address1_Latitude as "address1_latitude"
, "systemuser0".Address2_StateOrProvince as "address2_stateorprovince"
, "systemuser0".Address1_County as "address1_county"
, "systemuser0".Address2_Country as "address2_country"
, "systemuser0".Address2_PostOfficeBox as "address2_postofficebox"
, "systemuser0".PreferredPhoneCode as "preferredphonecode"
, "systemuser0".new_RegistrationNumer as "new_registrationnumer"
, "systemuser0".YammerUserId as "yammeruserid"
, "systemuser0".Title as "title"
, "systemuser0".SetupUser as "setupuser"
, "systemuser0".FirstName as "firstname"
, "systemuser0".EmployeeId as "employeeid"
, "systemuser0".Address1_Line2 as "address1_line2"
, "systemuser0".Address1_City as "address1_city"
, "systemuser0".YomiFirstName as "yomifirstname"
, "systemuser0".ExchangeRate as "exchangerate"
, "systemuser0".Address1_ShippingMethodCode as "address1_shippingmethodcode"
, "systemuser0".YomiMiddleName as "yomimiddlename"
, "systemuser0".Address2_Line2 as "address2_line2"
, "systemuser0".DefaultFiltersPopulated as "defaultfilterspopulated"
, "systemuser0".ModifiedOnBehalfBy as "modifiedonbehalfby"
, "systemuser0".Address2_Line3 as "address2_line3"
, "systemuser0".DefaultMailboxName as "defaultmailboxname" 
from
 SystemUser as "systemuser0" 
where
 (("systemuser0".IsDisabled = 0)) order by
 "systemuser0".SystemUserId asc
```

Now when I run this query at SQL level, the result came up in less than 2 seconds. ***So my confusion is why it takes more time on CRM Front end side?***
Apart from, the time that it takes for data rendering at CRM Front end level, I can not think anything else.

My Second confusion is when I run this query and other where I was getting warning messages with no lock in query itself, it was way faster than even 2 seconds.

What I am thinking is to write logic that will apply at DB level and whatever query hits the DB will have by default NO LOCK in it.

Is it possible even? PLEASE let me know how to get rid of these warning messages.

Thanks.

Comment: It's more than likely going to be a bad idea to apply nolock on everything. You'd be better off profiling the database to identify the locks and checking what the expensive queries are and getting to the root of the problem as opposed to brushing it under the rug.

Comment: This makes sense, I just did data profiling on that particular DB. I got like thousands "Lock Acquired" and "Lock Released" in span of 1 minutes only. what should be my next step based on your thought of analyzing it!

Comment: You can use isolation level of READ UNCOMMITTED for this but I would HIGHLY recommend you not do that. Unless of course you are ok with randomly getting duplicate and/or missing rows. In other words it might be ok if you are cool with getting mostly accurate results most of the time. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: I agree with you , I don't want to go this path since we want accurate result in report as well as our search in MS Dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

By running the query `at SQL level` I don't know whether you mean running it directly from the SQL Server console, but I think I can offer some insight as to why it appears to take longer when running `on CRM Front end side`.  When you run the query directly from SQL Server, most of the time you already have an active connection to the database.  This means that you don't have to wait to establish a connection, and the two big holdups would be waiting for the query to execute, and waiting to receive the result set.

However, when you run the query from your CRM front end, you presumably would have to establish a connection before you even begin the query.  Setting up a connection can take longer than you might think.

So, a good test to run would be this: Execute your query twice, back-to-back, from the CRM front end and clock the running time of each one.  If the second query runs much faster, than you may have discovered that the cost of establishing a connection with your SQL Server.

Comment: bad query plans too

Comment: You are absolutely right but the issue you there are more than 300 user who are live on Dynamics right now. There is now way I guess to find out the user for query which I posted above and go to that user and repeat the the whole process again. In App log it doesn't load any info about the users.

Comment: Is there any way to relate this warning message to particular user, than I can go to that user an find out what exactly he was searching at that time as Tim mentioned and can request him to do same thing from two different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same famous problem we usually get when command times out in ado.net but works fine in Management Studio. I think there are several fixes out there but since you don't have control over the query so try these 2 commands on the DB in question

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Comment: Ok Let me try this one.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend running a Query Execution Plan so that it'll tell you if any queries might be improved by adding indexes.

Also, why are you trying to pull 5k records at once? Is that generated from custom code or something? CRM views are way less than that, i.e. 50-200 records. By pulling so many records at once you're increasing the likelihood of having database locks.

Comment: You are right on the spot Jordi, it's custom code. when I run the query in SQL Server I get only 27 rows. This query is being generated from CRM which always has TOP 5001, I don't know even why. I would like to take that out, since I am not CRM guy i don't know how to do it.